# How to compare each value with Max value for a Project with in the same column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to calculate Max score - each score for a project in pandas Dataframe

current df looks like this:

```
projectID supplierID score
1         1          50
1         2          60 
1         3          75
```

I want it to look like this:

```
projectID supplierID score diff_to_max
1         1          50    25
1         2          60    15
1         3          75    0
```

and I want to do this action for each projectID

Answer (score 3):

Broadcasting with `transform` and subtracting

```
df.groupby('projectID').score.transform('max') - df.score
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-straight forward but fast/cool way using Numpy

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.projectID)
score = df.score.values
out = np.empty(len(r), score.dtype)
out.fill(score.min() - 1)

np.maximum.at(out, i, score)

df.assign(diff_to_max=out[i] - score)

   projectID  supplierID  score  diff_to_max
0          1           1     50           25
1          1           2     60           15
2          1           3     75            0
```